# HTTP trigger azure function won't bind route parameter with encoded slashes

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I've created an Azure C# HTTP triggered function with a route url: `subscriptions/{token}/t`. It works fine for urls such as `subscriptions/blah/t` but it fails with a `404` for parameters that contain encoded slashes: `subscriptions/blah%2fblah/t`. Any way around this ?

Before we get into debates, `{token}` is a URL encoded Base64 string which will naturally contain slashes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue seems to persist. 
I found out that it can be resolved by double-escaping the string, that is, applying escaping recursively two times.

```
token = escape(escape(token));
```

In .NET you can use `URI.EsacpeDataString()`
In JS you can use `encodeURIComponent()`

Note, that single escaping does not work reliably with Azure functions

Answer (score 0):

> but it fails with a 404 for parameters that contain encoded slashes: subscriptions/blah%2fblah/t.

It is make sense because 'subscriptions/blah%2fblah/t' is equal to 'subscriptions/blah/blah/t'. I suggest you define your own encode rule for slashes.  For example, you could convert all the slashes to '[[-]]'. Your token will be like this 'subscriptions/blah[[-]]blah/t'. After received the token, you could convert the special characters back.

```
token = token.Replace("[[-]]", "/");
```

Comment: Agreed, but what's the purpose of encoding the parameter other than making sure it hits my action/function as it is (with slashes ...) ?

Comment: How many slashes in your token? Is it a fix size? If yes, you could modify your route URL to match it. Otherwise, you need to encode your token using your own ways.

Comment: Any update? If you have further questions, please feel free to let me know.

Comment: I've ended up encoding the slashes and equals to something less offending, I'll do a report in the azure forums though, that doesn't sound right...